# Accessing http://developers.facebook.com/apps always redirects to my "Company" Page

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, user-permissions

Every time I try to access http://developers.facebook.com/apps, I'm redirected to my Company page. I'm trying to set up an application that I can use on my site, but this makes it very difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 3):

You are hitting the company's firewall, which prohibits programmers from using Facebook in work time...

This is certainly not a question for Stack Overflow (this site is for programming questions), such questions are better asked on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Apologies. The page on Facebook Developers suggested asking here. And by "my Company", I mean the company I set up within facebook. Not my employer.